# How to register iOS app to support OPML file type?

Tags: ios, opml

How to register an app to handle `.opml` file type? This is what I've tried adding to `Info.plist` file

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>OPML</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.opml</string>
            <string>org.opml.opml</string>
            <string>net.multimarkdown.opml</string>
            <string>com.apple.news.opml</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

With keys defined above when `.opml` file is opened via "Open in ..." app does not show up in the list of apps that can handle this file type.

I've noticed that if `public.data` is added in the `LSItemContentTypes` array it does show the app in the "Open in..." list but app is shown for all other undesirable file types. Is there a specific content type that is missing?

Comment: You are not exporting your file type. This is not a standard file type known to the system, so if you don't export it, the system can't see it as a public type.

Comment: Try adding entries to the Imported Type Declarations for the OPML related UTIs.

Comment: @matt indeed that was the issue, thank you for the hint!

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *declaring* a file type, but that type is not a built-in known type (such as PDF), and you yourself are not *exporting* that type; therefore it is not seen by the runtime as publicly available to other apps.

Comment: While it works either way, I would choose to put these under Imported type declarations and not Exported type declarations. I use Exported type declarations for new UTIs invented by my app. I use Imported type declarations for non-publicly available declarations that are not specific to my own app. These OPML UTIs are not unique to this person's app. Functionally it doesn't matter but it's a way to organize UTI declarations.

Comment: Found a technical note on this topic `https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html` for the custom document type, or a document type that iOS does not already know about, they recommend to use exported UTI. But to keep UTI declarations organized following convention @rmaddy suggested makes a lot of sense to me

Comment: @Digitech What 'Identifier' / 'Comforms To' values did you use in the "Imported UTIs" Section to get OPML files to be imported?

Comment: @EmmettHarper Identifier `public.opml` Confirms To `public.data`